# Select text between any two HTML html nodes?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to select text between any two given HTML nodes (in the order thats visible to user).

As an example in following screenshot(https://aws.amazon.com/connect/faqs/), I want to select answer between two questions.

> Yes. We encourage you to go to the Amazon Connect console and set up
> an Amazon Connect contact center now.

[image]

**Edit:**

In another works I am looking for completion of this function

```
// firstElement and secondElement don't need to be related.
// They dont be part of same subtree
    
   function getBetweenElements(firstElement, secondElement) {
    
       ...
    
      return result;
    }
```

Comment: its just an example. the site I am working, i have full access to DOM

Comment: Puppeteer is what you need. parse with it and select content with the simple CSS selector

Comment: I can use Puppeteer but I dont think its that easy. Since I dont know what css selector should I use

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are looking for but what I understand from your last comment you need a selector to select all the answers.

please try this selector `.lb-rtxt p:nth-child(even)`. To test selector you can open the page, open the console and enter this js code `document.querySelectorAll('.lb-rtxt p:nth-child(even)')`. You can change the string selector according to your need.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there is a *newline* after every paragraph (`<p>` tag). The `text` in the `childNodes` has a `nodeValue` of `'\n'`.

[image: The text has a nodeValue of '\n']

Notice they have no `id` or class selector in particular that is helpful. They're just plain `<p>`s.

So, something like this should work:

```js
const answer = document.getElementById("answer");
const els = Array.from(answer.childNodes);

// filter out the 'text's

const pEls = els.filter((el) => (el.nodeName === "P"));
const answers = pEls.filter(pEl => (pEls.indexOf(pEl)%2 !== 0));

// do whatever with the answers
console.log(answers.map(ans => ans.innerText.trim()));
```

```html
<div class="lb-txt-16 lb-rtxt" style="color:#232F3E;" id="answer">
    <p><b>Q: Can I really set up Amazon Connect in minutes?</b></p>
    <p>Yes. We encourage you to go to the <a href="https://console.aws.amazon.com/connect/home">Amazon Connect console</a> and set up an Amazon Connect contact center now.</p>
    <p><b>Q: Do you have examples of how customers are already using Amazon Connect?</b></p>
    <p>Yes. Please see the <a href="/connect/customers/">Amazon Connect customers</a> web page and the <a href="https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/contact-center/">AWS contact center blog channel</a>.<br> </p>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry but this wont work. This answer is very specific to amazon website. I want a general solution.

Comment: @dasfdsa this very clearly answers what your question asks. If you want it to be more "general" we need to have a look at your code because we can't tell what you exactly need without knowing your DOM structure.

Comment: i have a question about text between two HTML nodes. ANY HTML nodes. you have given me answer between two HTML Paragraphs nodes.

Comment: @dasfdsa again, it is not too easy. Can't know what two elements you want the text between without knowing what distinguishes them. We need a selector so that we can get the text between those two elements.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getBetweenElements(firstElement, secondElement) {
  let result = [];
  let nextEl = firstElement.nextElementSibling;

  while (nextEl !== secondElement) {
    result.push(nextEl);
    nextEl = nextEl.nextElementSibling;
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(
  getBetweenElements(
    document.getElementById("first"),
    document.getElementById("second"),
  ),
);
```

```html
<p id="first">hello 1</p>

<p>my 1st paragraph</p>
<p>my 2nd paragraph</p>
<p>my 3rd paragraph</p>
<p>my 4rd paragraph</p>
<p>my 5rd paragraph</p>

<p id="second">hello 2</p>
```

**the idea:**

1. get the next element after the first selected element using `Element.nextElementSibling` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling
2. do a while loop to check if nextElement is equal to the last element.
3. if the `while()` loop is finished, now we can return a array.

Comment: Thank you. Its a good answer but it wont work if the firstElement and secondElement aren't in same hierarchy.

Comment: Your didn't specify the html in your question. If it is relevant then add it to your question. Otherwise this is a good answer.

Comment: In question title I have asked for text between *any* two html nodes

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you solve your problem :

```
    <!-- common section using html -->
<section id="mySection">
    <h2>first title</h2>
    <div>first div</div>
    <h2>secund title</h2>
    <div>secund div</div>
    <h2>third title</h2>
    <div>third div</div>
</section>
<script>
    // Defining a variable to put the extracted texts inside
    const myItems = []
    // Select the section using javascript
    const fatherElement = document.getElementById("mySection")
    // Here we make a loop on the children of the section
    for (const children of fatherElement.children) {
        // And if the son has a specific tag, we extract the text from inside it and put it in the variable of the extracted texts
        if (children.tagName === "DIV") {
            myItems.push(children.innerText)
        }
    }
    console.log(myItems); // ['first div', 'secund div', 'third div']
</script>
```

We can also use the id of the element instead of the tag name or any other distinctive detail of the elements we want